# Shell script to find file and copy file from other location

Tags: shell, unix

I'm puzzeling with a shell script.

What am I trying to achieve?

- In my 'upload2website'-folder on my Mac I have numerous files that have the following *AA_bestandsnaam-xx.jpg* or *AA_bestandsnaam - xx.jpg* (Watch the spaces). xx is a filenumber, could be any number.
- Below the 'upload2website'-folder there a several subfolders.
- In the subfolder below upload2website there are the origins of *AA_bestandnaam-xx.jpg* or *AA_bestandnaam - xx.jpg*
- If the file is in *upload2website* is found in one of the subfolders, then copy it to the folders *uploads*
- It is possible that the AA is placed at the end of the file, f.i. *bestandnaam-xx_AA.jpg*

**Example of the structure**

upload2website-folder

- AA_bestandsnaamA-68.jpg
- AA_bestandsnaamB - 01.jpg
- AA_bestandsnaamC-106.jpg
- AA_bestandsnaamD-30.jpg

subfolders

- upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-13.jpg
- upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-28.jpg
- upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-68.jpg
- upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-90.jpg
- upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 08.jpg
- upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 09.jpg
- upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 10.jpg
- upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 13.jpg
- upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 01.jpg
- upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-08.jpg
- upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-90.jpg
- upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-105.jpg
- upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-106.jpg
- etc.

The following script I'm working on, but that doesn't work, f.i. if there are spaces in the name, than name is truncated as of the first space. I already added -iname and quotes around the variables.

```
#!/bin/sh
SRCDIR=upload2website
DSTDIR=uploads
PREFIX=FB_
UPLOAD=`ls "$SRCDIR"/*.jpg`
#SEARCH=`$UPLOAD | sed "/$PREFIX/s///"`
for src in $UPLOAD
do
   # echo source: "$src"
   test="`basename "$src"`"
   FBname=`basename "$src"  | sed "/$PREFIX/s///"`
   # name=`basename "$src"`
   # echo name: "$name"

   #dst=`find "$DSTDIR" -name "$FBname"`
   dst=`find "$SRCDIR" -iname "$FBname"`
   # if [ "$dst" != "" ]; then

   if [ "$dst" != "" ]; then
    echo FBname: "$FBname"
     echo cp "$dst" "$DSTDIR"
   fi
done
```

Can somebody please help me to get the script right?

**Update: Clarify folders**

the folderstructure:

- /Users/gjdegraaf/Documents/upload2website  <<<--- contains subfolders and origin of the image files
- /Users/gjdegraaf/Documents/uploads. <<<--- should contain the copied origin of the file that matches the file without AA_

Comment: What should the execution of your script output? Which files should be copied where for the input provided?

Comment: The origin of the file found in one of the subfolders below *upload2website* should be found and copied to uploads.

Comment: So `cp upload2website/AA_bestandsnaamA-68.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/AA_bestandsnaamB - 01.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/AA_bestandsnaamC-106.jpg uploads` should be the output from your script? Please try not to describe, rather please _show_ what should happen. or `cp upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-68.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 01.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-106.jpg uploads`? And why you describe the prefix to be `AA_` yet your script has `FB_`?

Comment: @KamilCuk the second part of your example should happen. Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `$(...)` instead of `. Backticks are discouraged`.
- Don't `for i in $(ls)`. Forget about `ls`. Never use `ls` in scripts. Forget it. Use `find`.
- Don't use uppercase variables for local variables. By convention uppercase variables are exported. And you can run into clashes, for example `RANDOM`.

I don't fully understand where is `uploads` dir and how is it related to `upload2website` dir and how the structure really is. But maybe the folowing code snippets will help you with some ideas.

Your script could look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
srcdir=upload2website
dstdir=uploads
prefix=FB_
# output a newline separated list of filenames in srcdir
find "$srcdir" -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -name '*.jpg' |
# read the newline separated list
while IFS= read -r src; do
   filename=$(basename "$src")
   # NOTE: here prefix is  FB_ not AA_ ....
   FBname=$(printf "%s\n" "$filename" | sed "s/$prefix//")
   # check if the file FBname exists in src folder
   if dst=$(
                    find "$srcdir" -maxdepth 1 -type f |
          grep "$FBname"
                    ); then
      echo cp "$src" "$dstdir"
   fi
done
```

Bu I would most probably do something like this, which needs bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
src=upload2website
dst=uploads
prefix=FB_

# find all files in src dir
find "$src" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" |
# remove all the `AA_`
sed 's@^AA_@@; s/_AA\.jpg$//;' |
sort |
# filter from the list the files from dst
# output only paths
join -t$'\t' -11 -21 -o2.2 - <(
    # a newline separated list with two tab separated columns
    find "$src" -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%f\t%p\n' |
    # sort on filename
    sort -k1
) |
# copy the files
xargs -I{} echo cp {} "$dst"
```

I [tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/GainsboroAdolescentDecimal) both scripts and they outputted:

```
cp upload2website/folder1/bestandsnaamA-68.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/folder2/bestandsnaamB - 01.jpg uploads
cp upload2website/folder3/bestandsnaamC-106.jpg uploads
```

But I don't fully understand which folder is uploads and which is not.

Both scripts still assume there are no newline in the filenames. It is possible to rewrite the second code snippet to use zero terminated streams, with GNU sed `-z` option, `find -print0`, `join -z`, `xargs -0` and `sort -z`. You can get around tabulation used for separator with good `cut -d$'\t' -f2-`, the following code uses gnu tools and bash and should be able to handle any filenames except those with the byte `0x01` in the filenames:

```
sep=$'\x01'
# find all files in src dir
find "$src" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\0" |
# remove all the `AA_`
sed -z 's@^AA_@@; s/_AA\.jpg$//;' |
sort -z |
# filter from the list the files from dst
# output only paths
join -z -t"$sep" -11 -21 - <(
    # a newline separated list with two tab separated columns
    find "$src" -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf "%f$sep%p\0" |
    # sort on filename
    sort -z -t$sep -s -k1
) |
cut -z -d"$sep" -f2- |
# copy the files
xargs -0 -I{} echo cp {} "$dst"
```

Comment: I added a folderstructure to clarify the meaning of the various folders. Thanks for your script. Is the maxdepth needed? Later I'll be behind my Mac and give it a try

Comment: find scans recursively by default. Without maxdepth, it will scan everything.

Comment: I had to install bash (brew install bash) and v3.2 is installed. If I rund the script, it gives me: bash-3.2$ ./stack.sh
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator
find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Have to find out how to solve the message.

Comment: Installed 'findutils' (brew install findutils), but still the same error on -printf

Comment: Did you try it in a new terminal after installing findutils? What is the output of `find --version`? Do you have that error for the first or second code snippet? I don't think the while loop snippet needs anything particular, posix shell could be enough.

Comment: CMD + Q to close all terminal sessions after reopening find --version gives me illegal operation -- 
The error occurs in the bash-script. To clarify, on my Mac I only run the bash-script as shown in repl.it Copy+pasted it to stack.sh and did chmod 700 stack.sh

Comment: The last script starting with sep=$'\x01' errors on line 10
➜  Documents ./stack1.sh
./stack1.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./stack1.sh: line 10: `join -z -t"$sep" -11 -21 - < ('

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
dst=`find "$SRCDIR" -iname "$FBname" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1 `
```

When reading filenames with spaces, you need to use `print0`, and you need to built it using `xargs` with `-0` option.

Comment: `-print0 | xargs -0 ls -1` why? What is the point of reading filenames with spaces, if you pass them to `ls -1` anyway and then save into the variable?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but this doesn't work @Guru. The files are not search in the subfolders and this only copies files from upload2website. Probably $FBname doesn't contain the correct names.

Comment: @user2037412 : did not notice subfolder, removing maxdepth.

Comment: @KamilCuk : if he has multiple files, how will he be able to parse without xargs..i am not aware....

Comment: Just `dst=$(find "$SRCDIR" -iname "$FBname" -type f)`?

Comment: It now searches in subfolders :) however it still not checks on the correct file meaning that it doesn't seem to search for files starting with AA_

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this in one line.

Your goal could be separated into the following steps

1. get the filename at the root of upload2website

   `find upload2website -maxdepth 1 -type f`
2. for each file, trim the path part, trim the leading "AA_"

   `x={}; x=${x##*/};`
   if he AA_ is always at the beginning, you can use `x=${x:3}` to substring it. but since you mentioned that it could also be at the end, you should add
   `x=${x#AA_};x=${x%_AA}`
3. get the filelist in subfolders

   `find upload2website -type f -mindepth 2`
4. use the grep to select the matched files, and copy them

so taken these together

`find upload2website -maxdepth 1 -type f|\
  parallel \
  'x={};x=${x##*/};x=${x#AA_};x=${x%_AA};  \
  find upload2website -type f -mindepth 2 |\
  grep "$x" -' |\
  parallel 'cp {} upload'`

I have just tested on my macbook and it works.

If you don't have parallel, you can install it by

`brew install parallel`

actually, if you are using parallel, you can just get the pure file name by
`$x={/}`  instead of 
`x={};x=${x##*/};`  above.

the result is like below

```
.
├── upload
│   ├── bestandsnaamA-68.jpg
│   ├── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 01.jpg
│   └── bestandsnaamC-106.jpg
└── upload2website
    ├── AA_bestandsnaamA-68.jpg
    ├── AA_bestandsnaamB\ -\ 01.jpg
    ├── AA_bestandsnaamC-106.jpg
    ├── AA_bestandsnaamD-30.jpg
    ├── folder1
    │   ├── bestandsnaamA-13.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamA-28.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamA-68.jpg
    │   └── bestandsnaamA-90.jpg
    ├── folder2
    │   ├── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 01.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 08.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 09.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 10.jpg
    │   └── bestandsnaamB\ -\ 13.jpg
    ├── folder3
    │   ├── bestandsnaamC-08.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamC-105.jpg
    │   ├── bestandsnaamC-106.jpg
    │   └── bestandsnaamC-90.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. Installed parallel, but sorry to say this script copies all files instead of finding the matching file without AA_ of _AA in the subfolders below 'upload2website' and copy them to 'uploads'. Made some addition to your result.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE / EDIT

Used the following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
src=upload2website
dst=uploads
prefix=FB_

# find all files in src dir
gfind "$src" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%f\n" |
# remove all the `FB_`
sed 's@^FB_@@; s/_FB\.jpg$//;' |
sort |
# filter from the list the files from dst
# output only paths
join -t$'\t' -11 -21 -o2.2 - <(
    # a newline separated list with two tab separated columns
    gfind "$src" -maxdepth **5** -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%f\t%p\n' |
    # sort on filename
    sort -k1
) |
# copy the files
xargs -I{} echo cp {} "$dst"
~                                                                                                                                                                         
~                                                                                                                                                                         
~                                                                                                                                                                         
"stack.sh" 20L, 518C written
```

The output (just put all output for the sake of clarity). Sorry for the worse lay-out. As you can see, it copies .DS_Store files too and these should not be selected, however these are easy to remove in de uploads-folder.

> ➜ Documents ./stack.sh cp upload2website/40MijlvanBru/**.DS_Store**
>   uploads cp upload2website/8Uur van de Oosterschelde/**.DS_Store** uploads
>   cp upload2website/Almere Regatta 2015/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Antwerpen-2019/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Antwerpen/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Beaucette-Lezardrieux/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Bembridge - Cowes/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Bocht van Guinea/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Boiler Isotemp/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Boot/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Boulogne/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Burnham-on-Crouch - Vlissingen/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Carteret-Dielette/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Elektra/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/GrandcampMaisy-Ouistreham/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Herkingen, Zuid-Holland - Jachthaven, 3 februari
>   2018/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/JWvdM/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Kajuitramen/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Kiel/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Koelkast/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Kuip/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Lazy
>   bag/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Littlehampton-BirdhamPool/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Lummelbeslag/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Lymington/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Middelburg-Veere/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Nieuwpoort-Blankenberge/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Onderwaterschip/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Onweer_NVvT/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Overtocht DCS/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Pasen_2019/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/PropOne-antifouling/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Roer/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Roer/Roer/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/001-Vertrek-Lowestoft/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/003-Wells-next-the-Sea/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/006-Whitby-Newcastle/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/007-Newcastle/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/008-Newcastle-Amble/.DS_Store uploads
>   cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/012-Edinburgh-Arbroath/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/016-Peterhead/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/018-Lossiemouth/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/024-Caledonian Canal-Fort
>   Augustus/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/026-Laggan Lock-Banavie/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/028-Banavie-Corpach Basin/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/029-Corpach
>   Basin-Dunstaffnage/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/031-Tobermory/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/036-Lamlash/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/038-Campbeltown-Belfast/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/039-Belfast/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/042-Dublin/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/050-Padstow-Newlyn/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/052-Fowey-Dartmouth/.DS_Store uploads
>   cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/053-Dartmouth-Weymouth/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje
>   Engeland/057-Eastbourne-Dover/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Rondje Engeland/061-St_Annaland-Herkingen/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Rondje Engeland/Krabbeltje/.DS_Store uploads
>   cp upload2website/Rondje Kanaal 2012/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Schroef/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/StVaast-GrandcampMaisy/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Te water/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Toilet/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Uisge/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Uisge/40Myl/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Uisge/UK/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/VDO
>   Urenteller/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/Vakantie 2014/.DS_Store
>   uploads cp upload2website/Vakantie 2015/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Veere/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Verkoop/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Verzekeringscasus/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomer 2016/.DS_Store uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/.DS_Store uploads cp upload2website/27
>   apr. 2007/1213030320_dscf1547_small.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Uisge/2.jpg uploads cp upload2website/Uisge/3.jpg
>   uploads cp upload2website/40MijlvanBru/40MijlvanBru-27.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/40MijlvanBru/40MijlvanBru-31.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/8Uur van de
>   Oosterschelde/8UurvandeOosterschelde-035.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Antwerpen-2019/Antwerpen-2019-14.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Antwerpen-2019/Antwerpen-2019-38.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Boiler Isotemp/Boiler-01.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Boiler Isotemp/Boiler-07.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Dek schilderen/Dek schilderen - 20.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Fenderhoes/Fenderhoes-08.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Herkingen, Zuid-Holland - Jachthaven, 3 februari
>   2018/Heat-exchanger-06.jpg uploads cp upload2website/Honfleur/Honfleur
>   - 21.jpg uploads cp upload2website/09april16/IMG_3799.jpg uploads cp upload2website/Kajuitramen/Kajuitramen - 92.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Kajuitramen/Kajuitramen - 95.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Kajuitramen/Kajuitramen±-±21.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Aanhechting kiel romp/Kitrand_romp_kiel-01.jpg uploads
>   cp upload2website/Koelkast/Koelkast - 15.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Koelkast/Koelkast - 30.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Koelkast/Koelkast - 36.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Lummelbeslag/Lummelbeslag - 09.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Onderwaterschip/Onderwaterschip-48.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Pasen_2019/Pasen_2019-15.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/PropOne-antifouling/PropOne-antifouling-06.jpg uploads
>   cp upload2website/Radiateur/Radiateur - 01.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Radiateur/Radiateur - 02.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Radiateur/Radiateur - 03.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Radiateur/Radiateur - 04.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Radiateur/Radiateur - 05.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Tewaterlating/Tewaterlating-01.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Uisge/Uitslag-Marathon2012.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Vakantie 2014/Vakantie 2014 - 129.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Waterpomp/Waterpomp - 4.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Waterpomp/Waterpomp - 5.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomer 2016/Duinkerken - Boulogne sur Mer/Zomer 2016 -
>   096.jpg uploads cp upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-09.jpg uploads cp upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-119.jpg uploads
>   cp upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-135.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-142.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-144.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-15.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-158.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-162-test.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-22.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-24.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-30.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-47.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-64.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-82.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-87.jpg uploads cp
>   upload2website/Zomervakantie/Zomervakantie-93.jpg uploads

If I count the number of files copied, I'm missig around 90 files. I don't know how to add a text file to this post otherwise I could show the files containing (AA_ of AA) actually FB or _FB but that's of no importance to the solution. It might be even so to take all *.jpg files from the upload2website folder and see if there is a occurence in one of the subfolders below upload2website.

** UPDATE 03jan20 **

Managed to modify the script to exclude files starting with a dot:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
src=upload2website
dst=uploads
prefix=FB_

# find all files in src dir
# gfind "$src" -maxdepth 1  -type f -printf "%f\n" |
gfind "upload2website" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname  ".*" -iname "*.jpg" \) -printf "%f\n" | 
# remove all the `FB_`
# sed 's@^FB_@@; s/FB//; s/_FB\.jpg$//;' |
sed 's@^FB_@@; s/FB//; s/_FB\.jpg$//;' |
sort |
# filter from the list the files from dst
# output only paths
join -t$'\t' -11 -21 -o2.2 - <(
    # a newline separated list with two tab separated columns
    gfind "$src"  -mindepth 2 -type f -printf '%f\t%p\n' |
    # sort on filename
    sort -k1
) |
# copy the files
xargs -I{} echo cp {} "$dst"
```

I think the join is missing some file, because

```
➜  Documents gfind "upload2website" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( ! -iname  ".*" -iname "*.jpg" \) -printf "%f\n" | sed 's@^FB_@@; s/FB//; s/_FB\.jpg$//;' | sort > tmp.txt
```

gives alle requested files from upload2website, however I'm missing a search to the files in f.i. the following folders: (again, sorry for the poor lay-out).

➜  Documents l **upload2website/Rondje\ Engeland/** total 5236192 drwxr-xr-x   89 gjdegraaf  staff   2,8K  2 jan 22:11 . drwxr-x-wx@ 431 gjdegraaf  staff    13K  2 jan 22:27 .. drwxr-xr-x   25 gjdegraaf  staff   800B  2 jan 22:11 **001-Vertrek-Lowestoft** drwxr-xr-x   13 gjdegraaf  staff   416B  6 jun  2019 **002-Lowestoft-Wells-next-the-Sea** drwxr-xr-x   74 gjdegraaf  staff   2,3K  2 jan 22:11 003-Wells-next-the-Sea drwxr-xr-x   12 gjdegraaf  staff   384B 10 jun  2019 004-Wells-next-the-Sea-Whitby drwxr-xr-x   21 gjdegraaf  staff   672B 15 jun  2019 005-Whitby drwxr-xr-x    9 gjdegraaf  staff   288B  2 jan 22:11 006-Whitby-Newcastle drwxr-xr-x   56 gjdegraaf  staff   1,8K  2 jan 22:11 007-Newcastle drwxr-xr-x   20 gjdegraaf  staff   640B  2 jan 22:11 008-Newcastle-Amble drwxr-xr-x   26 gjdegraaf  staff 832B 24 jun  2019 009-Amble drwxr-xr-x   25 gjdegraaf  staff   800B 24 jun  2019 010-Amble-Edinburgh drwxr-xr-x   19 gjdegraaf  staff   608B 26 jun  2019 011-Edinburgh drwxr-xr-x   12 gjdegraaf  staff   384B  2 jan 22:11 012-Edinburgh-Arbroath drwxr-xr-x   18 gjdegraaf  staff   576B 28 jun  2019 013-Arbroath drwxr-xr-x   10 gjdegraaf  staff   320B 29 jun  2019 014-Arbroath-Peterhead drwxr-xr-x   20 gjdegraaf  staff   640B 30 jun  2019 015-Aberdeen-Peterhead drwxr-xr-x   28 gjdegraaf  staff   896B  2 jan 22:11 016-Peterhead drwxr-xr-x   10 gjdegraaf  staff   320B  6 jul 07:41 017-Peterhead-Lossiemouth drwxr-xr-x   44 gjdegraaf  staff   1,4K  2 jan 22:11 018-Lossiemouth drwxr-xr-x    7 gjdegraaf  staff   224B 12 jul 19:08 019-Lossiemouth-Cromarty drwxr-xr-x   20 gjdegraaf  staff   640B 17 jul 08:24 020-Cromarty drwxr-xr-x    7 gjdegraaf  staff   224B 17 jul 08:27 021-Cromarty-Rosemarkie Bay drwxr-xr-x   11 gjdegraaf  staff   352B 17 jul 08:28 022-Rosemarkie Bay-Inverness drwxr-xr-x   20 gjdegraaf  staff   640B 19 jul 06:34 023-Inverness-Caledonian Canal drwxr-xr-x   34 gjdegraaf  staff   1,1K  2 jan 22:11 024-Caledonian Canal-Fort Augustus drwxr-xr-x   27 gjdegraaf  staff   864B 22 jul 08:04 025-Fort Augustus-Laggan Lock drwxr-xr-x   12 gjdegraaf  staff   384B  2 jan 22:11 026-Laggan Lock-Banavie drwxr-xr-x   61 gjdegraaf  staff   1,9K 25 jul 08:01 027-Ben Nevis drwxr-xr-x   14 gjdegraaf  staff   448B  2 jan 22:11 028-Banavie-Corpach Basin drwxr-xr-x   20 gjdegraaf  staff   640B  2 jan 22:11 029-Corpach Basin-Dunstaffnage

Could someone help me with the join in the script? I do understand how a join works, however not in scripting. Thanks!